# Creating list from data in loop

Tags: python

I have a loop that produces a number denoted as trap for multiple datasets. I am trying to put all of the trap numbers into one list so that I am able to find the average of them. When I try to put them into a loop, only the last number of the loop goes into the list.

*Going through this code, it essentially grabs data for stress and data for strain. As the dataset changes in the loop, so does the stress and strain. It then uses the trapezoid rule to find the area under the curve. Next, the areas under the curve should be placed into the list so I can find the average, but the list only contains the last value.

```
for dataset in samplenums:
    data = np.array(get_data("0h UV Exposure, Roll Direction",dataset))
    moredata = np.transpose(data)
    Stress = moredata[:,1]
    Strain = moredata[:,0]

    trap = integ.trapz(Stress,Strain)
    print("The toughness calculated using trapazoidal rule for dataset", dataset, "is",trap)

    list = []
    list.append(trap)
    print(list)
```

Comment: You initialise `list` in each iteration of the loop. Move `list = []` above the loop.

Comment: You are creating empty list every time as list=[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your code as below, you have few mistakes.

1 - No need to create a new list every time so declare it outside of the loop.

```
list = []
for dataset in samplenums:
    data = np.array(get_data("0h UV Exposure, Roll Direction",dataset))
    moredata = np.transpose(data)
    Stress = moredata[:,1]
    Strain = moredata[:,0]

    trap = integ.trapz(Stress,Strain)
    list.append(trap)
    print("The toughness calculated using trapazoidal rule for dataset", dataset, "is",trap)

    print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new `list` each time (inside the loop) and appending the data (`trap`) to it. What you need to do is create the `list` before entering the loop and then append the data inside the loop.